# How to format input values in Play framework 2?

Tags: java, scala, view, playframework, playframework-2.0

How can I format an input value to have 2 decimal places in Play! framework 2?  For example, I want a price to look like "100.00", but its showing up as "100.0".  Do I do it with an annotation on the model, or a parameter on the input in the form?

I tried this but it doesn't change the format:

```
@inputText(myForm("price"), 'format -> "###.##")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I changed the data type from Double to BigDecimal and set the scale to 2.  This automatically handled formatting it.

```
@Column(scale = 2)
public BigDecimal price;
```